# Just need a clarification on a simple probability question.

Tags: probability

So I'm looking for the chance of getting an Even and Large die roll. Even(2,4,6) Large is defined as (4,5,6) Small is defined as (1,2,3)

So I get that by using addition rule the answer is simply the case that when the die roll turns out to be either a 4 or 6, therefore the chance of that happening is $\frac{1}{6}$ + $\frac{1}{6}$

However if I were to use multiplication rule to solve this problem can I think of it this way:

{P(Getting an even number) $\cdot$ P(getting a large number) } $\cdot$ 2 <--(the number of ways we can arrange the two)

Therefore the probability should be ($\frac{1}{6}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{1}{6}$) $\cdot$ 2= $\frac{2}{6}$

Thank you!!

Comment: The "Multiplication" rule can only be applied when the events are independent, of which they are clearly not.  Also, that is not the right multiplication rule (that is for getting a 2 and a 4 on two rolls of the die).

Comment: @GrahamKemp ahh I remember now, so in this case it's a conditional probability it's a case of P(B|A) then it's just $\frac{2}{6}$ Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Multiplication" rule you used is for evaluating the chance of getting a `4` and a `6` on *two seperate* roles of the die (and the answer for that should be $2/36$).   That's not what you want.

The event you are measuring is that for getting a `4` or `6` on *a single* roll of the die.   These are clearly not independent events (nor are the events Even and Large independent).   So the actual multiplication rule (for independent events) cannot be used either.

Rather, use the rule for conditional probabilities.

$$\mathsf P(\{2,4,6\}\cap\{4,5,6\})~=\mathsf P(\{2,4,6\})\mathsf P(\{4,5,6\}\mid\{2,4,6\}) \\= \tfrac 36\cdot \tfrac 23 \\= \tfrac 26\\[3ex]=\tfrac 16+\tfrac 16\\=\mathsf P(\{4\})+\mathsf P(\{6\})\\=\mathsf P({4,6\})}$$